# Join selections

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

How I can join this queries to single select (without temp table)?

```
SELECT  t2.value,
        t1.value
    FROM table0 t1
    INNER JOIN table1 t3 on t1.idrelation = t3.id and t3.idparent=@id
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t2.idversion = t3.idchild and t2.name = 'FOO'
    ORDER BY t1.value

SELECT SELECT COALESCE(t4._NAME+','+'') 
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2 on t2.idparent = t1.idchild
JOIN table1 t3 on t3.idparent = t2.idchild
JOIN table3 t4 on t4._ID = t3.idchild
WHERE t1.idparent = @id
AND t4._TYPE ='TXT_CAT'
```

Comment: How do you want to join it? t2.value, t1.value, t4._NAME?

Comment: can you post some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to join them, there has to be common or uncommon ground.

Putting the 2 selects together is the easy part when you join the resultant sets, but unless you want all permutations of Ans1 and Ans2, then it is wise to determine some sort of where clause to allow it to be more effecient, and narrow it down for you.

If you give more table information, We could be able to adjust and give you something further, but that is the best we can do without taking arbitrary guesses as to what you are trying to accomplish here.

One thing i can part unto you:

```
 Select A.name, B.id from (Select A.name, A.date from A) join (Select B.id, B.date from B) on A.date = B.date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would help (once you can tell the columns on which you want to join):

```
select *
from
(
    QUERY 1
) q1
join
(
    QUERY 2
) q2
on q1.key1 = q2.key2
```